# How to parse html with php DomXpath, modify and save

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

After googling could not found anything related to my issue.
Problem is: I parse page, find one table [there is four tables].

And when I found, I want to add one/some row/rows to table. But I don`t know how to do it. Some similar issues are about parsing xml and viewing content.

In code I have something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($output->getHTML());
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tableProp = $xpath->query('//*[@class="smwb-factbox"][2]');
....
$dom->asHTML();
```

Comment: Can you show what is the content of `$output->getHTML()` or at least a part of it and I'm not aware of function `$dom->asHTML();` do you mean `$dom->saveHTML();` ?

Comment: sorry, you are true, it's saveHTML

Comment: Now everything works fine ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple:
With set of methods such as createElement, setAttribute and appendChild I solved my problem, example as follows:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($output->getHTML(), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tableProp = $xpath->query('//*[@class="smwb-factbox"][2]');
...
$th_el = $dom->createElement('th', $th_outer_inner_span_a_el);
...
$td_el = $dom->createElement('td', '');
$td_el->appendChild($td_el_outer_span);
$tr_el = $dom->createElement('tr', '');
$tr_el->setAttribute('class', 'smwb-propvalue');
$tr_el->appendChild($th_el);
$tr_el->appendChild($td_el);
$tableProp->item(0)->appendChild($tr_el);
$dom->saveHTML();
...
```

The idea is pretty simple.
I have table in mediawiki, find it, create new row and insert it, after save it. That's all.